# How should I go about animating particles in python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, simulation

For my homework, I am instructed to write a script that simulates the gas particles within a container.

Now I have done the math part and so far it works as this:

1) input a initial-list that contains the position coordinates and movement vector
2) a converted list is then created, consisting of all the x coordinates and y coordinates, each in a separate sublist, for later plotting
3) then run a series of functions I wrote that updates position and vector within the list after the interval
4) convert the list again
5) and so on

However I simply can't find out how to animate these?

I guess I need something like:

1) plot a circle to use as container + the initial particles/positions
2) keep the circle and update the list
3) plot circle and updated list
4) and so on, in very fast speed

Answer (score 6):

Here a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
points, = ax.plot(np.random.rand(10), 'o')
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

def update(data):
    points.set_ydata(data)
    return points,

def generate_points():
    while True:
        yield np.random.rand(10)  # change this

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, generate_points, interval=300)
ani.save('animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=4);
plt.show()
```

[image]